# Uwp cannot lower the width of textbox to less than 70

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

The problem I'm having is that if I set textbox's width to under 70, it won't be shown fully. I've set the `MinWidth` to 0 and the `TextBox` still displays as the lower textbox in the following image. The upper one's width I set it to 70 and it displays fully. Is there something I need to change in the template to make it work? any ideas?

[image]

```
<TextBox
    Width="30"
    Height="50"
    MinWidth="0" />
```

Also I tried to edit the template of the `TextBox` in Visual Studio's designer. I clicked edit template and nothing happened, but it worked fine with other controls.

my original codes:
I set the first textbox's width to 50 and rest to 70.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0">
                    <controls:DropShadowPanel
                        BlurRadius="40"
                        ShadowOpacity="0.3"
                        Color="{StaticResource blueColor}">
                        <TextBox
                            Width="50"
                            x:Name="Code0"
                            Height="80"
                            MinWidth="0"
                            Background="White"
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource blueColor}"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="10"
                            FontSize="55"
                            TextAlignment="Center" />
                    </controls:DropShadowPanel>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0">
                    <controls:DropShadowPanel
                        BlurRadius="40"
                        ShadowOpacity="0.3"
                        Color="{StaticResource blueColor}">
                        <TextBox
                            Width="70"
                            x:Name="Code1"
                            Height="80"
                            MinWidth="0"
                            Background="White"
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource blueColor}"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="10"
                            FontSize="55"
                            TextAlignment="Center" />
                    </controls:DropShadowPanel>
                </Grid>
                 ...
```

it looks like this [image]

updates:

```
<controls:DropShadowPanel
                        BlurRadius="40"
                        Width="80"
                        Background="Red"
                        ShadowOpacity="0.3"
                        Color="{StaticResource blueColor}">
                        <TextBox
                            x:Name="Code0"
                            Width="50"
                            Height="80"
                            MinWidth="0"
                            MaxWidth="65"
                            Background="White"
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource darkText}"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="10"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                            FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="{StaticResource blueColor}"
                            FocusVisualSecondaryBrush="{StaticResource blueColor}"
                            FontSize="55"
                            KeyDown="TwoFactorKeyDown"
                            TextAlignment="Center" />
                    </controls:DropShadowPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question. What is your desired outcome? Do you want the width of the bottom to be 50? Also, its very hard to determine what the problem is without the rest of the XAML.

Comment: my desired outcome is to display textbox properly with a width less than 70. Right now you can see when I set it to 50 it is only shown half. I think the problem is due to textbox only because its parent's width is auto so the width is not limited by the parent.

Comment: Can you post the xaml of the parent container?

Comment: I just updated, the other five textboxes are identical as the first one except their widths are 70, the first one is 50.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the width of the textbox actually has no effect to the width of its inner template, judging from the fact that actual textbox's size is actually changed to 50 but the template within seems to have the same size still

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Uwp cannot lower the width of textbox to less than 70

The red circle area is TextBox Border. and it's `MinHeight` and `MinWidth` are  `TextControlThemeMinHeight` and `TextControlThemeMinWidth`.So if you just `MinWidth` property, the border `MinWidth` will not be changed.

[image]

```
<Border x:Name="BorderElement"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" 
        Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" 
        MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" 
        MinWidth="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"
        Grid.RowSpan="1"
        Grid.Row="1"/>
```

If you want to change TextBox's min width completely, you could add the following in your page Resources

```
<Page.Resources>
    <x:Double x:Key="TextControlThemeMinHeight">32</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="TextControlThemeMinWidth">0</x:Double>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly the answer I'm looking for,

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I do not think your textbox is the issue. I believe your problem is with the width of your controls:DropShadowPanel. I suspect that your grid column is sizing to the textbox, but your DropShadowPanel is just getting clipped or cutoff. Try setting the width of your DropShadowPanel to 60 ( this will allow a little extra room for the borders and gradients around the textbox ) it will also force the column to adjust to the width of DropShadowPanel.

Comment: unfortunately the problem is still there. I set the dropshadow's width to 80 and background to red in order to confirm that there is free space around. Can you look at my update